# Why is ‘Archive…’ disabled in Evolution (or how to enable it)

Tags: 19.10, evolution

In Evolution 3.34.1-2 (Ubuntu 19.10), I have selected a message, but the archive button – and the corresponding menu entry – is disabled. Why is that so?

[image: Evolution screen shot with disabled menu item]

And ‘yes’ – I have selected a folder to be the archives folder. You can spot it in the upper-left corner of the screenshot.

Comment: Probably, you need to indicate an "archive" folder in your server settings before the option becomes available.

Comment: Gosh, why on earth is there an extra setting in the server section? What does the _other option_ do, which I already found and which turned the folder icon into the archives symbol (as you can see in the screenshot)? Anyway, @vanadium, turn that comment into an answer and it will be accepted.

Comment: Ok, there you go ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Archive" right-click menu requires you to first setup a dedicated folder. To that aim, create an "Archives" folder (any name will do), and then, in your account settings, set that folder to be the "Archive folder" (see Figure). This feature is also available in Thunderbird, and is set up in a similar way (under "Copies & Folders" in the "Account Settings" dialog).

Figure: The "Account Editor" screen in Evolution ([Source](https://ttboj.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/testing-evolutions-git-master-and-gnome-continuous/))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set this up with Gmail, set your Evolution `Archive` folder to be the `All Mail` folder to preserve the "Gmail way" of IMAP organization.

[image: screenshot of Evolution settings for Gmail]